# Add program to firewall exceptions list

Tags: c#, windows, windows-firewall-api

I have a WCF Service running on port 8000, but I have also a firewall enabled. I am using this code to try to add my program to the firewall exceptions list, so I can use the service without disabling the firewall. Also, I want to do that automatically. Thats why in my previous researches, I found this link: [Automating Windows Firewall with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889587/automating-windows-firewall-with) (I was using a modified version of the `clsFirewall` to just add the program to the white list, no ports.)

To allow in/out traffic, I used `netsh advfirewall firewall ad rule` command to add a rule for my port.

Even though the port are indeed added to the rules list, aswell as my application, it doesnt seem to work with the firewall enabled. I am using http://www.canyouseeme.org/ to check the port. It only works when I disable my firewall.

What might be going wrong?

I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Does it work if you add the port and your application to the rules list *by using the Control Panel interface*?

Comment: I didn't even realize programs could add themselves to the firewall.... wow whas the point in having a firewall then?

Comment: @Steve - most apps that do this do it during setup which is n explicit action by the end user to install an app (and want it to work).  The firewall still has value block ports which the user and app installs haven't explicitly opened.  Also, most responsible apps inform they are doing this.

Comment: It only works if I `disable` my firewall. I dont want to disable it, just add an exception. I don't want to add it manually in the Control Panel Interface, I want to make it fully automatic. And yes, the user will be aware of that modification.

Comment: @steve, only adminstrators can do this, so non-privileged programs cannot.

Comment: @LeandroBattochio, Are you using the Windows firewall or a third-party one like Sophos, Norton, etc???

Comment: @Ben Just windows firewall.