# How can I block a port using Wix?

Tags: wix, port, firewall, wix-extension

I've got an installer that installs the oracle XE database.  Recently, I've been asked to close/block port 1521 programmatically during installation.  My app is installed using Wix 3.8.  I've seen the Wix Firewall Extension, but I don't see a way to specify the action  (i.e., "block").  I want to block all incoming traffic on that port, effectively shutting down the listener.

Is there another way to do this or am I missing something with Wix?

Comment: Looking at the Wix Firewall Extension it seems that it doesn't provide the functionality to block a port, only to create an exception to grant access through a port. Maybe another option is to create a C# custom action, and use some API to control the firewall from there? Unfortunately I have no experience with this, so I don't know for sure if it's possible, or how it could be done.

Comment: I think you are correct, Akos.  I'll work on a custom action and post back when I have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

In case the **Wix extension** doesn't support this (which would surprise me), perhaps you can try this VBScript.

Note that I didn't write this script, nor have I used it. **Use with caution and at your own risk**. Test on a virtual machine.

```vb
Set objFirewall = CreateObject("HNetCfg.FwMgr")
Set objPolicy = objFirewall.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile
Set colPorts = objPolicy.GloballyOpenPorts

Set objPort = colPorts.Item(9999,6)
objPort.Enabled = FALSE
```

Similar code, but using C#: [Automating Windows Firewall with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889587/automating-windows-firewall-with)

Comment: it surprises me too, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't.  I'll proceed with a custom action and post back with my solution (unless someone else proves me wrong WRT to the extension)

Comment: @SirLanceAlot Did you find a good solution? I need the same thing. I will assume you are long gone and start writing my own solution to the problem and post back here when something works well.

Answer (score 1):

Update: We weren't able to get WiX installer to do what we wanted, so we wrote our own custom process (not a CustomAction) that runs post install.

The 3 mains steps were:

1. Configure the sqlnet.ora (\database\app\oracle\product\\server\NETWORK\ADMIN\sqlnet.ora) file to only allow connections from the localhost by appending the following lines:

> ```
> > TCP.VALIDNODE_CHECKING=YES
> > TCP.INVITED_NODES = 127.0.0.1
> ```

2. Set up the TNSListener for local access only by running the following sqlplus commands:

> ```
> > exec DBMS_XDB.SETLISTENERLOCALACCESS(true);
> >     SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE
> >     STARTUP
> ```

3. Stop the OracleXETNSListener service and disable it (custom VB.net code)

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Shadoninja, see if this ^^^ helps.