# c# Firewall rule multi profile

Tags: c#

How to set firewall rule in c# for all?
I tried to set for only domain or private and it works great. But for all code, it does not work.
I use code from GitHub, this solution https://github.com/falahati/WindowsFirewallHelper

part of code:

```
  var rule = FirewallManager.Instance.CreateApplicationRule(FirewallManager.Instance.GetProfile(FirewallProfiles.All).Type, @"MyApp Rule", FirewallAction.Allow, @"C:\MyApp.exe");
  rule.Direction = FirewallDirection.Inbound;
  FirewallManager.Instance.Rules.Add(rule);

  [Flags]
  public enum FirewallProfiles
  {
     Domain = NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE2.NET_FW_PROFILE2_DOMAIN,
     Private = NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE2.NET_FW_PROFILE2_PRIVATE,
     Public = NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE2.NET_FW_PROFILE2_PUBLIC,
     All=NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE2.NET_FW_PROFILE2_ALL
  }
```

and i catch `exception =FirewallLegacyNotSupportedException`

Answer (score 1):

You can not get a profile for all profiles. There is no `All` profile in the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security (Vista+). This library is simply a wrapper around the Windows Firewall COM API and you need to have basic information about the underlying system to be able to use it. 
Secondly, getting the profile by passing a `FirewallProfiles` and then using the `Type` property is essentially equal to passing the `FirewallProfiles` directly to the method.

```
      var rule = FirewallManager.Instance.CreateApplicationRule(
        FirewallProfiles.Private | FirewallProfiles.Domain | FirewallProfiles.Public, 
        @"MyApp Rule", 
        FirewallAction.Allow, 
        @"C:\MyApp.exe"
      );
      rule.Direction = FirewallDirection.Inbound;
      FirewallManager.Instance.Rules.Add(rule);
```

Please ask questions like this via the Github issue tracker.
https://github.com/falahati/WindowsFirewallHelper/issues

Answer (score 0):

SUGGESTION: Try adding this to your app.config/web.config:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Specifically:

> [MSDN: Compatibility: Using the CAS Policy Legacy
>   Option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/misc/code-access-security-policy-compatibility-and-migration#compatibility-using-the-cas-policy-legacy-option)
>
> The  configuration element lets you
>   specify that a process or library uses legacy CAS policy. When you
>   enable this element, the policy and evidence overloads will work as
>   they did in previous versions of the framework.
>
> **Note**:
>   CAS policy behavior is specified on a runtime version basis, so
>   modifying CAS policy for one runtime version does not affect the CAS
>   policy of another version.

ALTERNATIVE SUGGESTION:

Look at the [INetFwOpenPorts API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/netfw/nn-netfw-inetfwopenports)

SUGGESTION #3:

Look at [this C# example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52358938/421195).

Please post back whether or not either of these work for you.  I'm crossing my fingers ;)!